# Thymeleaf to check null and display value accordingly

Tags: html, tooltip, thymeleaf

How to display `user_name` and `user_id` inside th:title.

HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget tooltip-wrapper" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" th:title="*{user_id} + ${'-' + creator.user_name}" > </div>
```

I need to check whether `user_id` is not null and also `user_name` is not null and display both in tool tip.

Sample :  `101 - Janet`

I tried with `th:title="*{user_id!=null} + ${'-' + creator.user_name}"`.
But it is displaying as `true` instead of the actual value.

Currently if the value is null, it is displaying as `null` in tooltip. But I don't want to display if the value is null or empty.

Can anyone help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
th:title="*{user_id?:''} + '-' +${creator.user_name?: ''}"
```

You can find more about conditional operator & Elvis operator on [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions).

Comment: Thanks. `th:title="*{user_id!=null} ?*{user_id}  " `. This is working, But  
`th:title="*{user_id!=null} ?*{user_id}   + $creator.user_name!=null} ?${   creator.user_name}"` is not working. Any help?? Thanks

Comment: th:title="*{user_id != null ?user_id:''} + ${creator.user_name != null ?creator.user_name : ''}". This should work. You will need :'' after ? operation, because you use concatenation with + after evaluating an expression.

Comment: I tried . Its not working. May be bacause `"` is being closed in between, its not recognizing as a valid HTML code

Comment: `th:title="*{user_id != null ?user_id:''} + ${creator.user_name != null ?creator.user_name : ''}"` Sorry, this should be the correct formatting.